# rust Axum trace logging automatically pick up errors

Tags: logging, rust, error-logging, rust-axum, rust-tracing

I'm trying to set up logging in an Axum app, I have the logging working but the thing that bothers me is the need to do `error("OHNOES SOMETHING WENT WRONG")` in every single error branch.

I did see `#[instrument(err)]` in the documentation but **A** I'm trying to avoid having to need to put `#[instrument(err)]` on every route handler and **B** I'm not sure that would work any way since Axum want's a `Response` not a `Result` to be returned from a given handler.

I did try to setup a stupidly simple error logging middleware:

```rust
#[instrument(name = "request")]
pub async fn main_response_mapper(res: Response) -> Response {
    if res.status() != StatusCode::OK {
        error!("{:?}", res.body());
    }
    res
}
```

But the body only reports with: `UnsyncBoxBody`, (something to do with needing to support infinite data streams) so I can't use a middleware for this.

Is there a way to have the logging automatically pickup that it got an error and log out its message? (the error implements `std::fat::Display`)

Comment: *"Axum want's a Response not a Result"* - an Axum handler needs to return something implementing `IntoResponse`, which `Result`s do as long as their success and error types implement it as well.

Comment: Well, that fixes one issue, is there no way to avoid putting `#[instrument(err)]` around every handler?